# Multiple recycleView are stacking

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've created an app with a main page that is going to have multiple sections with recycleView data.  I have added the first but when I try to add a second (eventually adding 4 to replace the APPS, OTHER, etc sections) the second recycleView shows up on top of the first one (see top left of image) instead of next to it like I would expect. I tried putting both of the recycleView widgets inside a boxlayout but the second RV still overlays the top.

The information should be filling the second box on the right here instead of overlaying on the far top left

[image]

```
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screenManager
            Screen:
                name: "monitor"
                CoverImage:
                    source: 'images/monitor.png'
                    # Darken the photo
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, .6
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Administration'
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                        elevation:5
                    BoxLayout:
                        ServerListWidget:
                        MountListWidget:
```

Please let me know if you need to see any additional code. I've also tried using a GridLayout with 2 cols

```
<MountListWidget>:
    id: mountListWidget
    recycleView: recycleView_mounts
    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(20)
        spacing: dp(10)
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(10)
            BoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,.1
                    # Use a float layout to round the corners
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                RecycleView:
                    id: recycleView_mounts
                    viewclass: 'MountWidget'
                    RecycleGridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        default_size: self.parent.width, dp(60)
                        default_size_hint: 1, None
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        width: self.minimum_width
                        spacing: dp(155), dp(0)

                             
<ServerListWidget>:
    id: serverListWidget
    recycleView: recycleView
    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(20)
        spacing: dp(10)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            BoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,.1
                    # Use a float layout to round the corners
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                RecycleView:
                    id: recycleView
                    viewclass: 'ServerWidget'
                    RecycleGridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        default_size: self.parent.width / 5, dp(60)
                        default_size_hint: 1, None
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        width: self.minimum_width
                        spacing: dp(155), dp(0)



<CoverImage@CoverBehavior+Image>:
    reference_size: self.texture_size

<MountWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        #size_hint_max_x: dp(360)
        size_hint_min_x: dp(150)
        orientation: "horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                # Use the on_press to print troubleshooting info, otherwise comment out
                on_press: print(self.background_color)
                padding: dp(10), dp(10)
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: dp(18)
                background_color: .5,1,1,.6
                halign: "left"
                valign: "top"
                size: 1,1
                text: str(root.name)
                bold: True
                color:  (1,1,1)

<ServerWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        #size_hint_max_x: dp(360)
        size_hint_min_x: dp(150)
        orientation: "horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                # Use the on_press to print troubleshooting info, otherwise comment out
                on_press: print(self.background_color)
                padding: dp(10), dp(10)
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: dp(22) if root.has_issue else dp(18)
                background_color: .5,1,1,.6 #utils.get_random_color(alpha=.6)
                halign: "left"
                valign: "top"
                size: 1,1
                # Show last 4 of server name
                text: str(root.name).upper()[-4:]
                bold: True
                color: utils.get_color_from_hex(warn) if root.has_issue else (1,1,1)
            Button:
                background_color: .5,1,1,.6
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: dp(22) if root.work >= 85 and root.work < 90 else dp(26) if root.work >= 90 else dp(18)
                valign: "center"
                halign: "center"
                text: str(root.work)
                padding: dp(8), dp(8)
                bold: True if root.work > 90 else False
                #      yellow                                             red                             white
                color: (1,1,0) if root.work >= 85 and root.work < 90 else utils.get_color_from_hex(warn) if root.work >= 90 else (1,1,1)
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that should add the UI elements? From the code above there is only the Administration toolbar and the toggle of the drawer. I'm not seeing the code with the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AWolf, I've added additional code now

Comment: it is possible to have a name collision here: `recycleView` and `RecycleView`. can you try changing the variable's name, maybe `recycle_View`, and try again? the other is a reserved component name so it has to stay same.

Comment: Thanks for the response @YılmazDurmaz, I've tried changing them to all unique but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: please try to give a minimum working(!) code. Strip parts specific to your work. try to reduce it to a single python file a kivi file. maybe on the way, you can discover a fix. else it will help us to fully replicate your issue.

Comment: by the way, I tried to connect the code you gave but failed. either your screen file ends short, or you use something else I haven't imagined. that is why it is best to get a minimal working set of codes to show the bug.

Comment: @ScottRowley I may be slow but, can you like edit the picture of the UI and put some sign with a marker where and what should go where? I mean I see some stuff that looks like is not where it should but at first glance is not easy to see what's going on. Besides, it would be easier for people to understand the problem and help you,. further more, it avoids mistunderstanding. You know what i mean?